# Symfony validator inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entity classes:

```
class A {

/**
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(3)
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $attempts;

}

class B extends A {

/**
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(5)
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $attempts;

}
```

And 1 test to check  that validation works correctly:

```
public function testSetAttemptsCount()
{
    $block = new B();
    $block->setAttempts(6);

    $errors = $this->getService('validator')->validate($block);
    $this->assertHasViolation($errors, 'attempts', LessThanOrEqual::TOO_HIGH_ERROR);

    $block->setAttempts(4);
    $errors = $this->getService('validator')->validate($block);
    $this->assertNotHasViolation($errors, 'attempts', LessThanOrEqual::TOO_HIGH_ERROR);
}
```

This test will not pass because it validates assert value from class A. 
Does anybody know how can I "rewrite" validation rule for field?

Comment: Interesting... One would say it should just work like this. Will be following this one.

Comment: Very interesting indeed... I can confirm that this is current behavior in `v4.1` and as was digging through the docs in order to find some clue, I have found an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15582) and Fabien's commit (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21053) which points in this direction. It seems that it was fixed in `2.7`, but reverted shortly after due to BC breakage... :(

Comment: Interesting indeed. One way to do it is to make class C out of class A, and create an abstract class A, that's extended by B and C. This does however not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, wrong issue link. The correct one is: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15950

Answer (score 5):

I am going to conclude my search for the solution for now. It is clear that there was an attempt to resolve this but it caused some sort of BC breakage, however I have not found any mentions of it (so we could better understand it). After all, major versions allow BC breaks and, in my opinion, either `3.0` or `4.0` were a good candidates for this, but somehow slipped thought.

The best lead I've got (but not sufficient nor ideal in any means) is the quote from [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#validation-metadata):

> This means you are able to add new constraints to a property, but you cannot override them
>   ...
>   To create your own validation, **add the constraints to a new validation group**

Indeed, defining own own validation groups could be a potential solution to this, but we are back to square one if we do not have a control over parent classes (and we usually don't). So, this would involve redefining all of the properties from base class in our child class. This really beats the purpose.

Derived on above, somewhat less funky solution can be applied, if we externalize our validation rules to `YAML` or `XML`. So, no annotations. In `YAML`, that would look something like this:

```
App\Data\Foo:
    properties:
        attempts:
            - LessThanOrEqual: 2
        another:
            - LessThanOrEqual: 5

App\Data\Bar:
    properties:
        attempts:
            - LessThanOrEqual: {value: 5, groups: [Overriden]}
        another:
            - LessThanOrEqual: {value: 5, groups: [Overriden]}
```

In the config example above, `Bar extends Foo` and we can copy and paste existing validation rules and stick the custom `group` (`Overriden` in my case) and use it. That way, we validate those constraints coming from parent class, that are of interest to us and include our own from child class. Slightly more effort is needed if parent class uses different validation rule format...

I am eager to see if anyone can come up with better aproach as I feel this should really work our-of-box...

Hope this helps a bit...